# rviz crash at boot-up using robot-upstart indigo

Tags: ros, rviz, robot-upstart, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to use robot-upstart indigo to start my `roslaunch` script automatically at boot-up, my launch file contains rviz and I'm looking to show lidar pointcloud.
When I reboot my laptop, nothing show up. I used this command to check whats the problem

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/upstart/velodyne.log -n 30
```

and I found this error

```
rviz: cannot connect to X server 
No handlers could be found for logger "roslaunch"
[rviz-12] process has died [pid 1354, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rviz/rviz -f /world __name:=rviz __log:=/tmp/0d6492c4-a815-11e6-997a-47731f04dcc5/rviz-12.log].
```

Does someone has an idea?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247880/rviz-crash-at-boot-up-using-robot-upstart-indigo/) by [Hamz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28509/hamz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could either be a permission problem, or there really is no X server running when `robot_upstart` starts your launch files.

If the first, see [robot_upstart: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0](http://answers.ros.org/question/207892) as a related question. To clarify: `robot_upstart` runs your launch files under the same user as the one that installed them, but (from [robot_upstart 0.2.0 documentation » The install script - permissions](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/robot_upstart/html/install.html#permissions)):

> The roslaunch which executes does not have its user’s group memberships.

This could lead to the `rviz` instance not having any access rights to the X server.

The second (and looking at the error message, likely) option is that at the moment that your jobs are being started, the X server hasn't started yet, and as RViz needs one, it can't continue.

PS (and pedantic): technically RViz didn't crash: one of the prerequisites for it to work is to have a working X server. Since it can't connect to one, it can't initialise the application successfully, and just exits (most likely [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/1be76af0a30dee736b9597640df7dabb45126aca/src/rviz/main.cpp#L46)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0